# Não consigo acessar login depois que insiro o email e senha do usuário

Tags: php

Fiz um sistema de login, só que não entra no sistema onde sempre retorna para a tela inicial e não entra na condicional que quero, acho que isso está acontecendo no arquivo **valida_login.php**.

Existe os seguintes arquivos onde logo abaixo estão em ordem:

- Arquivo **conexao.php** (Conexão com o banco de dados)
- Arquivo **login.php** (Tela principal de login)
- Arquivo **valida_login.php** (Verifica se o usuário está cadastrado no sistema, o erro está por aqui, pois sempre cai na condição de retorna a tela login)
- Arquivo **classe_usuario.php** (Possui ao método Logar())
- Arquivo **oi.php** (Depois que o email e senha forem válidos, essa página deve ser liberada ao usuário)

```
// Arquivo conexão
<?php

    session_start(); // Necessário o uso de sessão

    global $conexao; // Variavél global criada para ser usada em qualquer parte do sistema
    // Variavéis para conexão
    $host = 'localhost';  
    $banco = 'web';
    $usuario = 'root';
    $senha = '';

    // Se for possível a conexão
    try {

        // PDO é extensão do PHP para conectar com o banco
        $conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$banco",$usuario,$senha);
        $conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ATTR_EXCEPTION);

    // Se a conexão não for possível
    } catch (PDOException $falha_conexao) {
        echo "Erro na conexão do banco".$falha_conexao->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $falha) {
        echo "Erro não proveniente a conexão do banco".$falha->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

```
// Tela login.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Login </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Bem vindo ao sistema </h1>
    <form method="POST" action="../Login/valida_login.php">
        <p> Email: <input type="email" name="login" placeholder="Digite seu email" size=30 
            required maxlength="50"> </p>
        <p> Senha: <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Digite a sua senha" size=30 
            required maxlength="32"> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" name="Entrar" value="Entrar"> </p>
        <p> Esqueceu sua senha? <a href="../Login/redefinir_senha.php"> Clique aqui para redefini-la</a> </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
// Tela valida_login.php
<?php
    // Se existir o botão Entrar
    if(isset($_POST['Entrar'])){
        // Se existirem os parâmetros e não forem ambos vazios 
        if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) 
        && isset($_POST['senha']) && !empty($_POST['senha'])){
            // Importando conexão
            require_once '../Login/conexao.php';
            // Importando a classe Usuario
            require_once '../Login/usuarios.php';
            // Criando uma instância da classe Usuario
            $u = new Usuario();
            // Valida as informações com segurança contra pessoas mal intencionadas
            $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
            $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);
            // Verifica o método
            if($u->Logar($email,$senha) == true){
                // Se existir a $_SESSION['id_usuario']
                if (isset($_SESSION['id_funcionario'])){
                    // Será redirecionado para a tela principal
                    header("Location: ../Login/oi.php");
                }else{
                    // Será redirecionado para a tela de login
                    header("Location: ../Login/login.php");
                }
            }
            // Se não, será redirecionado para a tela de login
        }else{
            header("Location: ../Login/login.php.php");
        }   
    } 
?>
```

```
<?php
// Tela classe_usuario.php  
    // Classe usuário
    class Usuario{
        // Método Logar
        public function Logar($email,$senha){
            // Recebe a variável global
            global $conexao;
            // Verifica se o funcionário existe no banco
            $login = "SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha";
            // Prepara a conexão com o banco
            $login = $conexao->prepare($login);
            // Vincula um valor a um parâmetro
            $login->bindValue(':email',$email);
            $login->bindValue(':senha',md5($senha));
            // Executa a operação
            $login->execute();
            // Condição que retorna o cd_funcionario (se houver)
            if($login->rowCount() > 0){
                // Retorna o array dos dados
                $dado = $login->fetch();
                // Variável global da sessão armazena a variável cd_funcionario
                $_SESSION['id_funcionario'] = $dado['cd_funcionario'];
                // Login feito
                return true;
            // Se não
            }else{
                // Login não feito
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

```
// Tela oi.php
<?php
    // Importa a conexão
    require_once '../Login/conexao.php';

    // Mensagem de teste
    echo "Seja bem vindo";

    // Se existir sair
    if(isset($_GET['sair'])){
        // Destrói todos os dados associados com a sessão atual
        session_destroy();
        // Retorna a tela de login
        header('Location: login.php');
        die(); // Saída
    }
?>

<p><a href="login.php" name="sair">Sair</a></p>
```

Comment: Verifique os logs do seu servidor para certificar-se que não ocorreram erros durante a execução.

Comment: A conexão com o banco funciona

Comment: Os nomes dos arquivos postados são os mesmos que você tem na aplicação? Pois o nome do arquivo que contém a classe `Usuario` se chama **classe_usuario.php**, mas no seu código você se refencia a ele como **usuarios.php**

Comment: @TiagoA ainda não é isso, eu mudei mas ainda não adiantou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que no formulário o campo entitulado "E-mail" está com `name` **login** e no php você está esperando uma chave **email** no `$_POST`:

De:

```
<p> Email: <input type="email" name="login" placeholder="Digite seu email" size=30 
            required maxlength="50"> </p>
```

Para:

```
<p> Email: <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu email" size=30 
            required maxlength="50"> </p>
```

Comment: O erro é auto explicativo: a constante `ATTR_EXCEPTION` não existe, vide: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php

Comment: Deu certo, eu não acredito que o erro era essa, muito obrigado. Eu tirei o ```$conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ATTR_EXCEPTION);``` do arquivo ```conexao.php``` porque tava dando erro.

Comment: Eu estou tendo problemas com o ```logout```, eu queria que o usuário não digite o index para não burlar o sistema de login ou que ele volte a página para não entrar na sessão sem digitar o email e senha, mas não posso postar no Stake Overflow por enquanto.

Comment: É só validar a sessão em toda página que você quer proteger, por exemplo, você cria um arquivo chamado **proteger.php** nele você faz uma verificação se a sessão existe e se a chave `id_funcionario` está preenchida, caso não, faça o redirecionamento para a tela de login com o `header("Location: ../Login/login.php");`.

Comment: Eu queria fazer isso dentro da página ```oi.php```, eu vou atualizar o código ```oi.php``` pra vc ver o que eu fiz.

Comment: Tem como vc atualizar a sua resposta colocando a solução do ```logout``` da página ```oi.php```?